# Send many things through a segue - Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, segue

Edit - not really a question anymore - please feel free to delete this post or use it as you wish. A little red box says this post is mostly code and Grammarly is kind of helpful too so just rambling on now until the little red box goes away.

Working solution:

ViewController1 ->

enum to tag many buttons - (change each button tag in interface builder)

```
enum Answers : Int, CustomStringConvertible {
    case bag = 1
    case bird = 2
```

enum for text

```
    var description : String {
        switch self {
        case .bag: return "Beg"
        case .bird: return "Birds"

        }

    }
```

enum for images - (stored in Assets)

```
    var pics : String {
        switch self {
        case .bag: return "beg"
        case .bird: return "birds"


        }

    }

}
```

Prepare segue - (storyboard should match identifier name)

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
     if segue.identifier == "ShowAnswers" {
        guard
            let controller = segue.destination as? proverbsViewController,
            let category = sender as? Answers
            else { return }

        controller.answer = category.description
        controller.image = UIImage(named: category.pics)!


    }
 }
```

Button to segue - all buttons are connected here (tagged in IB)

```
@IBAction func onButtonTap(_ sender: UIButton) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "ShowAnswers", sender: Answers(rawValue: sender.tag))

   }

}
```

Recieve data:

ViewController2 ->

```
var answer = ""

var image = UIImage()
```

Comment: Is it a question ?

Comment: Nah - its an answer to an original question that I posted and then solved before any else replied. And since I couldn't find a solution anywhere and finally solved it myself, decided to leave it here, it might relevant to others.

Comment: You shouldn't edit your original question to include the solution you found, but rather answer your own question with the working solution.